# How to manipulate protein interaction network from String database in R?

Tags: r, bioconductor, database, networks

How can I manipulate protein-interaction network graph from the String database using `STRINGdb` bioconductor package and R?

I have downloaded the whole graph for *Homo sapiens* from STRING, which has about 20.000 proteins.

1. How do I read the file using that package?
2. How do I filter things I don't need? Supposing that I want to keep tumor data, as an example.

Comment: Cross-posted [on biostars](https://www.biostars.org/p/255227/)...again

Comment: I don't think it is a problem to cross-post. It would be good to post a link to the best answer on the other site when such an answer is defined.

Comment: @bli that what I'm going to do once an answer is found

Comment: That's the question how do I do to filter things I don't need I already downloaded the whole graph for homosapiens from the download section in STRING .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the easiest way is to download the graph using `STRINGdb`.

```
library(STRINGdb)
string_db <- STRINGdb$new(version="10", species=9606,
                          score_threshold=400, input_directory="" )
full.graph <- string_db$get_graph()
```

Now you can use [`igraph`](http://igraph.org/r/), to manipulate the graph. Let's assume you want to take 200 proteins with the highest degree, i.e. number of edges they have.

```
library(igraph)

# see how many proteins do you have    
vcount(full.graph)

# find top 200 proteins with the highest degree
top.degree.verticies <- names(tail(sort(degree(full.graph)), 200))

# extract the relevant subgraph
top.subgraph <- induced_subgraph(full.graph, top.degree.verticies)

# count the number of proteins in it
vcount(top.subgraph)
```

**How to get disease specific genes?**

There's no GO annotation for cancer or Alzheimer's disease. It is out of scope of the GO consortium.

What you can do, you can either take KEGG Pathways annotation, or manually select list of relevant GO-terms. Or acquire the list from one of the papers. For example annotation term `05200` corresponds to the cancer KEGG pathway. You can easily retrieve proteins associated with the annotation:

```
cancer.pathway.proteins <-
    string_db$get_term_proteins('05200')$STRING_id
```

And then perform subgraphing as described above.

Alternatively you can try to get an enrichment score for an every gene given it's neighbors (the way enrichment is shown on the string-db website). Then you can keep only those having top enrichment scores. Probably `get_ppi_enrichment_full` or `get_ppi_enrichment` functions will help you to do that.

Comment: If we want to keep tumor , cancer , alzheimer data , I mean filtering by disease. can we do that ? knowing that we want to keep the maximum of nodes

Comment: @I'm getting errors Error in induced_subgraph(graph, top.degree.verticies) : Not a graph object

Comment: That's probably because `graph` is a function in `igraph` package. Make sure you're using a correct variable name.

Comment: is there a way to export the graph is csv ?

Comment: Please, check the very good documentation of the `igraph` package. You can export graph using `write_graph`. Also, as you can notice `STRINGdb` downloads the full graph to your computer, therefore you probably can download it directly from the database website.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59614/discussion-between-a-m-and-iakov-davydov).